# Java Spring application - Exception sending context initialized event to listener i

Tags: java, spring, jvm

I have java spring application which uses spring 3.0.7 with the following spring jars

spring-aop-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar

spring-asm-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar

spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar

spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar

spring-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar

spring-data-jdbc-core-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar

spring-expression-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar

spring-jdbc-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar

spring-tx-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar

spring-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar

This application is working fine in many of the VMs. But in one VM it throws the following exception while the server starts up.

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of
    class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
```

Any pointers is appreciated.

Entire exception stacktrace:

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
May 13, 2015 3:28:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testCacheLoader': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.util.localization.LoadLocaleMessage com.caching.testCacheLoader.llm; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loadLocaleMessage': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.common.dao.CommonDAO com.util.localization.LoadLocaleMessage.commonDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commonDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.caching.testCache com.common.dao.CommonDAOImpl.testCache; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testCache': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)

@PostConstruct
public void init() { 
    cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(100)
                .refreshAfterWrite(8, TimeUnit.HOURS).removalListener(listener)
                .build(loader);

        ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors
                .newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (String key : cache.asMap().keySet()) {
                    cache.refresh(key);
                    logger.info("Refreshing cache . . . . ");
                }
            }
        }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        try {
            cache.get("LOCALIZATION");
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post the **entire** exception. Don't format your entire post as code.

Comment: Thanks Boris for the reply. Updated the entire exception

Comment: I would hypothesise that your `CacheLoader` returns `null` for `LOCALIZATION` under some circumstances. Guava caches cannot have `null` keys. Incidentally why on earth do you have an expiry of 8 hours and then a separate thread to refresh elements every 5 minutes?? This all seems very dodgy. Just expire after 5 minutes and be done with it.

Comment: Are you saying only expiry every 5 minutes is enough? no need to refresh?                                                                                            cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(100)
                .refreshAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES).removalListener(listener)
                .build(loader);

Answer (score 3):

Look at the last part of the exception:

```
Error creating bean with name 'testCache': 
    Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
    com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException:
    java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How does the init-method of your `testCache` bean look - that's where the fault is (a NullPointerException).

Cheers,

Comment: added the init method. i do not see anything wrong with init

Comment: Yes you are correct init method is the problem. I am using google cache. That is creating problem. Thanks for finding out the actual problem. Still looking why that google cache is creating problem...

Comment: Thank you very much @Anders R. Bystrup ! My problem got solved. If you see in my init method there was no null check on cache. After adding null check it started working perfectly. Once again Thanks! I do not have enough reputation to accept your answer. You saved my day.

Comment: Great you found the root cause. Happy coding!

Comment: @user1457957 you don't need _any_ reputation to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). You need reputation to upvote. Please accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: yes i upvoted this. How can i accept this answer. Where i should do that